# How can I get the real page load time (after reloading) using puppeteer?

Tags: web-scraping, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless, har

**I have some problems with the page load time when I reload the page.**

**Steps to create an har :**

```js
context = await this.browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext()
const page = await context.newPage()
page.setCacheEnabled([false])
await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 0})
await cookieAcceptBtn.click();
```

*capture Network events (create CDP session, methods, Network.setCacheDisabled etc ...)*
*like this : https://github.com/sitespeedio/chrome-har/issues/19).*

```js
await har.register_events(page);
const tic = Date.now()
await page.reload({ waitUntil: "load", timeout: 0})
console.log(`second page load took: ${Date.now() - tic}ms`)
await page.waitFor(15000)
const har_results = await har.get_har();
await promisify(fs.writeFile)(resultPath + filename + '.har', JSON.stringify(har_results));
browser.close()
```

Results in the HAR :

```js
onContentLoad   3312.98
onLoad  20710.422
entries […]
```

When I put `${Date.now() - tic}` on the first load, load = 8000 ms 
When I put `${Date.now() - tic}` on the second load, load = 20000 ms

**Question : How can I get the real page load time (after reloading)?**